# vb.net/Linq: how can I use a Linq using Generic classes?

Tags: vb.net, linq, generics

I have the next structure:

```
public class mysample

    public property status as integer

end class

Dim mylist=new List(Of mysample)

Dim item as new mysample
item.status=1
mylist.add(item)

Dim item1 as new mysample
item2.status=1
mylist.add(item1)
...
```

I have next function which it is calculating something:

```
Function test(Of T)(newstatus as integer, mylist as List(of T)) as integer

    Dim res as integer = myList.Where(Function(x) x.status=newstatus).First.status

    Return res

End function
```

The call is where I am interested to execute: `test(Of mysample)(2, mylist)`

I have mysample in different projects and they can not be in the same for this reason I decided to use generic list to do my Linq calcultion.

THE PROBLEM IS IN FUNCTION WHICH TELL ME STATUS IS NOT MEMBER OF T OBJECT.

How can I solve this issue? all clases has status but I have different classes  and I pass the name as generic type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the classes share a common base class or interface?  If so you should place a filter on the generic type like this:

```
Function test(Of T as CommonBaseClassOrInterface)(newstatus as integer, mylist as List(of T)) as integer
```

That will allow you to access any members on `CommonBaseClassOrInterface`.  If they currently don't share a base class or interface you should consider adding one, making sure that `Status` is a member.

If you can't give them a base class or interface for some reason, you can still do this using reflection, but I DO NOT recommend going that direction.

Comment: I am agree with your comment about reflection in this case

Answer (score 1):

> STATUS IS NOT MEMBER OF T OBJECT.

Yes, because *you have not constraint `T` in any way*.  It would be perfectly legal to call

```
test(Of Integer)(2, new list(of Integer))
```

which would fail because `Integer` does not have a `status` property. You either need to constrain `T` to be of some type that has a `status` property (either a base class or a common interface), or *don't make it generic*:

```
Function test(newstatus as integer, mylist as List(of mystatus)) as integer

    Dim res as integer = myList.Where(Function(x) x.status=newstatus).First.status

    Return res

End function
```

> I have mysample in different projects

You mean you have several classes names `mystatus` in several projects?  Then *they are not the same class*.

> all classes has status but I have different classes and I pass the name as generic type

The create at least an interface that has a `Status` property and use *that* to constrain the generic parameter in `Test`.

Comment: did you read about question? I have several entities with status property in common. It is the typical case to use an interface. Your solution it is bad because manually I inserted in clases nut no working as you said. I tested before. The solution is the interface.